# Mplab X IDE insists I'm trying to change protected boot memory even though all CodeGuard options are disabled

Tags: pic, mplabx, pickit

I'm new to this whole thing, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, but [the only relevant thing](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m573023.aspx) I could find is over 9 years old, using a different programmer and different PIC.

I'm using MPLAB X IDE v5.35, trying to program a dsPIC30F6015 using PICkit3, and I get the "You are trying to change protected boot memory" error. However, under `Project Properties > XC16 > xc16-ld > CodeGuard` all options are set to "no" ("no flash", "no_eeprom," etc.)

Under "Generated command line" I have:

```
--stack=16 --check-sections --data-init --pack-data --handles --isr --no-gc-sections --fill-upper=0 --stackguard=16 --library-path="." --no-force-link --smart-io -Map="${DISTDIR}/p6015.${IMAGE_TYPE}.map" --report-mem
```

I'm not familiar with the flags, but I assume they reflect the whole "no" settings.

The person who originally programmed the thing is using a PICkit2, and when he programs the device, it works properly. He says he doesn't need the "Boot, Secure and General Segments" option chosen, but for me it's either choosing that or getting an error.

I'm not sure he uses the MPLAB X IDE to program it. I imported the project he sent me as an MPLAB IDE V8 project, so he might be using an older version of the MPLAB IDE, but I can't find MPLAB IDE V8 on the microchip website, and I'm reluctant to download things from sites I'm not familiar with, especially since I'm working on this in a lab in a university.

Another problem I'm having is that when I program the PIC using the code I got, it just doesn't work. I can't imagine security settings interfering with the code serving its purpose, though I can imagine it happening when there's a bug in the code. (The size of an allocated array is too small, and data is written to/read from indices that are out of bounds. I guess I should've tried again after fixing it, which I will do when I'm back at the lab, which is why this "other problem" is more of an off-hand thing. I didn't want to modify his code because when he programs the PIC, it works).